# Haxe PHP vs PHP - what language is better for creating Plugins for WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, haxe

I want to create a WP plugin with use of WP DB tables and costume ones, Ajax requests Rss feeds reading and writing and media storing and Google maps. Such a crazy plugin it will be...

So Haxe PHP or normal PHP - what language is better for creating Plugins for WordPress?

BTW books blog articles and docs are appreciated as proofs for your answer…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haxe can translate to pure PHP, but in this case why would you need Haxe in the first place?!

Use PHP.

Comment: I know flash ActionScript and a littel of C++ but no PHP...(

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Go for pure PHP. Haxe/PHP brings a lot of overload just for the bootstrap and handeling WordPress data structures could be a mess (since Haxe wraps a lot of stuff).